# why button3 doesn't move after set the layout_gravity="right"?

Tags: android

The following is my Activity.xml file.and I have set the button layout_gravity="right",but it doesn't work ,Could anyone can tell me why?thanks advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:tools=" http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" > 



<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_width="303dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="0.99" 
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:layout_weight="0.99" 
android:baselineAligned="_baseline" 
android:orientation="horizontal" > 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Button" /> 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Button" /> 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button3" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:text="Button" /> 

</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try giving layout_width as 0dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supposed to, that's why.

right layout_gravity is only considered if your layout is vertical, in which case it will have the expected result.

For what you are trying to do, use a spacer between second and third button, like this:

```
<View android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

It will fill the space and push your button to the right.

Comment: nota: as of android 14, there is a Space widget. I don't think it does much more, but at least the name says what it does.

Comment: I have changed the design ,but I will have a try of  it.